# Why doesn't my op amp circuit produce output as low as the simulation?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I'm working on a design to test/qualify vintage AT power supplies.  I want to test all (+5v, +12v, -5v, -12v) rails.  I want to be able to measure from -20% to +10%.  I've got a DAC (built into my microcontroller for now) which can measure from 0v to 3.3v.  To build in safety margins I want the outputs to be +/- 10% from that or 0.3v to 3.0v.

I'm intentionally stretching my skills a bit: they're strong with digital circuits but less so in analog.  I believe I should be able to use an op amp here, and a quad op amp chip will match the four rails I want nicely.  The primary reference I'm using is "[Op Amp Gain and Offset Page](http://earmark.net/gesr/opamp/gain_offset.htm)" which can mostly automatically suggest the exact circuits I need to set up, and the resistor values to use.  For three rails, this has worked great!  I've even (LTSpice simulated and) breadboarded the results and with only minor tweaks I get exactly what I'm hoping for.

Except with the +5v rail.  For that, it suggests case 2 and the case 2 page is broken.  If I download and fix it, I get completely broken results (all solutions have huge errors -- maybe I didn't fix it perfectly?).  If I instead use [Designing Gain and Offset in Thirty Seconds](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa097/sloa097.pdf) I get the same *m* and *b*, and a resistor network.  That's (I'm using a +5v reference, though I could be flexible a bit there if it helps)

[image: "30 second" solution, simulated]

completely wrong, per simulation?  Output is way too high, above the input rather than below.  (This is probably a hint that I'm "doing something wrong", but I don't know what.)  Somehow I figured out that "case 8" from the earlier-linked page seems to work, so I tried that and it gives:

[image: "case 8" solution]

An acceptable-looking solution.  And the simulation

[image: "case 8" simulated]

matches perfectly.  But when I breadboard it (edit: with GND at 0v and V+ at 12v) an input at about 4.2v produces about 0.7v output **and lower inputs never produce a lower output**.  I'm using potentiometers for my resistors, and a DIP LM324N quad-op-amp.  These same components have worked great, producing the expected output range, for my other three input ranges (and their matching appropriate circuits).

Am I running into a real-world op amp limitation that the simulation does not cover?  On a hunch, I repeated the "case 8" solution with an output range from 1.0 to 3.0v -- that works as expected on the breadboard, and seems to be a workaround I could select.  But I'd like to use the full output range down to 0.3v.

Comment: My only question is why do you think you need op-amps for this?

Comment: I want to both scale and offset four different voltages (and invert two of them).  Happy to hear different solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The LM324 cannot sink current greater than (typically) about 50uA without some substantial output voltage (approaching a diode drop) and your topology requires it to do so. It would have to sink Vref/(Rf+Rg) to get the output to zero.

You can make the LM324 outputs range from 1V to 3V and it should work with a 5V supply.

Comment: This does seem to be the underlying issue.  Larger Rf and Rg make things behave the way I'm hoping for.

Answer (score 3):

> *Am I running into a real-world op amp limitation that the simulation
> does not cover?*

The op-amp you chose probably needs to have a small negative rail so that the output can adequately reach 0 volts.

Even so-called rail-to-rail op-amps struggle to get closer than a few tens of milli volts and, regular op-amp outputs usually can't get within a volt of the power rails.

You also need to ensure that the input voltage range is within the power supply range of the op-amp and, in particularly, for the LM324, it's output limits at around 3.5 volts on a 5 volt positive supply.

Comment: I targeted 0.3v as the low end output partially to avoid trying to drive all the way to the zero volt V- input.  But moreover, as I said, I'm getting the expected 0.3 to 3.0 volt output, for other input ranges (and resistor networks).  I'll edit in my V- and V+.

Comment: Please don't edit in amendments that make my answer look like I didn't read your question properly.